# View is not updating in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have an app where I have a list, and a user can delete items from the list.

Here is the service that holds the initial list and the function that removes items from said list:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Services {
  public items: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'Tarek learns Angular',
      subheading: 'He now knows Angular!',
      subtext: 'He adds another framework to his techstack!',
      avatar: 'https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/013/564/doge.jpg',
      date: 'Friday July 20th 2018',
      isNewItem: true
    },
    {
      title: 'Human throws frisbee',
      subheading: 'Dog catches frisbee!',
      subtext: 'Dog is a good boy!',
      avatar: 'https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/013/564/doge.jpg',
      date: 'Friday July 20th 2018',
      isNewItem: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Human sdfgsfsdfthrows frisbee',
      subheading: 'Dog cadsfsatches frisbee!',
      subtext: 'Dog is a good bvsdfvsdvoy!',
      avatar: 'https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/013/564/doge.jpg',
      date: 'Friday July 20th 2018',
      isNewItem: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Humavsdvsdn throsdvsdvsdvws frisbee',
      subheading: 'Dog cavsddsvstches frisbee!',
      subtext: 'Dog is adsvsdfeegedsf good boy!',
      avatar: 'https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/013/564/doge.jpg',
      date: 'Friday July 20th 2018',
      isNewItem: false
    }
  ];

  numberOfNewItems: number = this.items.map(function (item) {
    if (item.isNewItem) {
      return item;
    }
  }).length;

  deleteItem = (itemObj: { itemTitle: string, itemSubheading: string, itemSubtext: string, itemDate: string }) => {
    const newItems: any [] = [];

    let numberOfFilteredNewItems: number = 0;

    const filterUndefined = this.items.map((item) => {

      if (item.title !== itemObj.itemTitle && item.subheading !== itemObj.itemSubheading) {
        if (item.subtext !== itemObj.itemSubtext && item.data !== itemObj.itemDate) {
          return item;
        }
      }
    });

    for (const item of filterUndefined) {

      if (item !== undefined) {

        newItems.push(item);

        if (item.isNewItem) {

          numberOfFilteredNewItems++;

        }

      }

    }

    this.items = newItems;

    this.numberOfNewItems = numberOfFilteredNewItems;

  };

  checkItemAsOld = (itemObj: { itemTitle: string, itemSubheading: string, itemSubtext: string, itemDate: string }) => {

    const newItems = this.items.map((item) => {

      if (item.title === itemObj.itemTitle && item.subheading === itemObj.itemSubheading && item.subtext === itemObj.itemSubtext && item.date === itemObj.itemDate) {
        return {title: item.title, subheading: item.subheading, subtext: item.subtext, date: item.date, isNewItem: false};
      } else {
        return item;

      }


    });

    let numberOfNewFilteredItems: number = 0;

    for (const item of newItems) {

      if (item.isNewItem) {

        numberOfNewFilteredItems++;

      }

    }

    this.numberOfNewItems = numberOfNewFilteredItems;

    this.items = newItems;

    console.log(this.numberOfNewItems);

    console.log(this.items);

  }
}
```

The `deleteItem` and `checkItemAsOld` are operating correctly, and are updating the values. Every time I console.log, it shows `this.items` and 'this.numberOfNewItems` updating correctly. But for some reason the view is not updating at all.

I made sure that in `app.module.ts`, I attached the Service to the `providers` array, and made sure that there were no `providers` arrays in the other components that could overwrite the providers array in the `app.modules.ts` file. Here is the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {ListComponent} from './ListComponent/list.component';

import {HeaderComponent} from './HeaderComponent/header.component';

import {ItemComponent} from './ItemComponent/item.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './FooterComponent/footer.component';

import {Services} from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ItemComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [Services],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In `app.components.html`, I passed down the items as such:

`<app-list [items]="items" [numberOfNewItems]="numberOfNewItems"></app-list>`

And here is the 'app.component.ts` file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {Services} from './services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() items: { title: string, subheading: string, subtext: string, avatar: string, date: string, isNewItem: boolean }[] = [];

  @Input() numberOfNewItems: number;

  constructor(private listServices: Services) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.items = this.listServices.items;

    this.numberOfNewItems = this.listServices.numberOfNewItems;

  }


}
```

I passed the items array to the `list.component.ts` file:

```
        import {Component, Input, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

    import {ItemModel} from '../ItemComponent/item.model';
    import {Services} from '../services';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-list',
      templateUrl: './list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
    })

    export class ListComponent {
      @Input() items: any [];
      @Input() numberOfNewItems: number;

      constructor(private listServices: Services) {
      }

    }
```

But still the view doesn't update even though `this.items` updates. Can anyone help me? I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your service you are updating the list reference when an item is deleted (basically copying the list into another array, and over-writing the previous reference):

```
this.items = newItems;

this.numberOfNewItems = numberOfFilteredNewItems;
```

But not updating the list reference used in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.items = this.listServices.items;

  this.numberOfNewItems = this.listServices.numberOfNewItems;

}
```

There are many ways to solve this to keep your references in synch.

One simple way is to bind to the reference directly:

```
<app-list [items]="listServices.items" [numberOfNewItems]="listServices.numberOfNewItems"></app-list>
```

Another way is to expose Observables from your service that your component can subscribe to whenever the list changes.

Finally, the third option: keep the list reference, just delete the item.  Why re-create the list as a new array reference when you don't need to.

```
deleteItem(item: any) {
    let i = this.items.indexOf(item);
    if (i >= 0) {
       this.items.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The 3rd option is probably the simplest, most typical way one would delete from a list.  This is also the option I recommend, followed by option 2, then option 1.

Comment: The third way isn't functional programming, so it's invalid JavaScript. /s